# How do i stop my vs code app from displaying the error pop up message

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

[image: the picture of the error message]

How do I stop my vs code from displaying the error pop-up massage in the red line every time I write a single line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl + j it will close your problem container.